# is something like this (LIKE operator) possible in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I started learning mysql 3 days ago and i try to do this exercise:

I have a mysql table name **testatable** with thousands of rows:

[screenshot of sample data from testtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb9kC.png)

It has 3 column `title, value and year`

When i try this query:

```
SELECT value FROM testatable WHERE title LIKE '%July%' AND title LIKE '%2015%'
```

it give me results like this:

```
more_value1
more_value2
more_value3
more_value4
more_value5
```

But is it possible that i can get nth row 'value' column data once LIKE Operator Finished Searching

Like in above results 2nd row will be 'more_value2'

My Question is Get nth row from 'value' column Which contain July And 2015 in title.

I try to search about it on Google but nothing found which can help me.

P.S. Thank for Stack Overflow Community. I already learned a lot in last 3 days about mysql from you guys.

Comment: For this use `LIMIT`

Comment: why not use - SELECT value FROM testatable WHERE title LIKE '%July%' AND year LIKE '%2015%'

Comment: @MariusBrits in some rows, year column is null thats why i used title column in both cases as it have year and month both values

Comment: cool glad you came right

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`OFFSET LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) :

```
SELECT value FROM testatable
WHERE title LIKE '%July%' AND title LIKE '%2015%'
LIMIT 1,1 /* This will fetch the second row , first number is the start position 
             and the second one is the amount of rows to retrieve*/
```

Note that this will fetch the second row based on random order.. if you want a specific order add an `ORDER BY` clause .

Comment: Maybe add a reference (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

And explain how it actually works: the first 1 means index 1, counted from an index of 0, which is the offset it starts the selection, then the second is the amount of rows from the offset

Comment: Was about to do it :) @Stian

Comment: thank you @sagi for your exact answer, and thank you for introducing me to the concept of OFFSET LIMIT. now i learned about it too.